# Thee.js Textures fineon one model and blurry on another (custom models)

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

So I'm pretty new to Three.js and so I'm following a tutorial on texturing custom geo which gave the classic head obj as a test file which is working.  I'm trying to edit the script to render my own custom geo instead but it makes the textures extremely blurry and pixelated.  I just added my geo and textures to the same paths as the example head and its still not working. is there something else I need to change?  Here is the snippet calling the material stuff

```js
 // load external geometry
 var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
 var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

 loader.load('/assets/model/Terrain/Terrain.obj', function (object) {
  var colorMap = textureLoader.load('/assets/model/Terrain/Terrain_Color.jpg');
  var bumpMap = textureLoader.load('/assets/model/Terrain/Terrain_Disp.jpg');
  var faceMaterial = getMaterial('phong', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');

  object.traverse(function(child) {
   if (child.name == 'Plane') {
    child.visible = false;
   }
   if (child.name == 'Infinite') {
    child.material = faceMaterial;
    faceMaterial.roughness = 0.875;
    faceMaterial.map = colorMap;
    faceMaterial.bumpMap = bumpMap;
    faceMaterial.roughnessMap = bumpMap;
    faceMaterial.metalness = 0;
    faceMaterial.bumpScale = 0.175;
   }
  } );

  object.scale.x = 20;
  object.scale.y = 20;
  object.scale.z = 20;

  object.position.z = 0;
  object.position.y = -2;
  scene.add(object);
 });

 // renderer
 var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

 var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

 document.getElementById('webgl').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

 update(renderer, scene, camera, controls);

 return scene;
}

function getMaterial(type, color) {
 var selectedMaterial;
 var materialOptions = {
  color: color === undefined ? 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' : color,
 };
```

[image: Image issue pictures]

Comment: Where is the rest of your `getMaterial` function? Why are you adding `bumpMap` to both bumpMap and roughnessMap? If you are using a phong material, it does not have roughness, roughnessMap and metalness AFAIK

Comment: Just an option. As your exported model filled with one colour, maybe it has wrong uv coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching the custom geometry and just loaded up my maps on a cube with an array, while bumping up the cubes divisions for a displacement map... which worked out fine since the custom geo was so close to a box anyways...